# How to create new Change Requests using TFS API 2010?

Tags: workitem, tfs-sdk, visual-studio-2010

I am new to the TFS API and currently in the process of creating new work items via a windows form app. Can anyone explain in detail with code examples on how to create new Change Requests, Risks and Scenarios for TFS 2010?

I was aware that CRs are not available in the Agile template but I saw somewhere that "Scenario" is the equivalent of "Service request/Change request" in the Agile template which is what we are using.

Are Risks and Requirements available in Agile? If yes, how to create them? I have finished adding new Bugs and Tasks successfully. Please tell me how to edit the work item xml templates if necessary too.

Thanks
Tara.

Answer (score 0):

To Edit the workitem templates you need to intsall "Process Editor".
After installation, Open the "Process Editor" and start editing WIT-WorkItem Type xml templates using visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a code example how to create with c# a new work item at http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2009/12/10/TFS-SDK-2010-e28093-Part-4-Create-a-new-User-Story-with-the-implementation-(Tasks)-and-test-scenarios-(Test-Case).aspx

To add the work items, the easiest is to retrieve them from the process template (download one from the web or download one that is already available in tfs: team -> project collection -> process templates). Then add the work item that you find in the downloaded location and you can upload that one with the command "witadmin importwitd" or with the process editor that comes with the [tfs power tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/c255a1e4-04ba-4f68-8f4e-cd473d6b971f)